# MVC async without waiting on task to complete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asynchronous

I make an ajax request to invoke a controller action like so:

Controller:

```
    [AsyncTimeout(8000, Order = 3)]
    [HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(TimeoutException), Order = 4, View = "TimeoutError")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> RemovePackageAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string packageId, ICollection<int> ids)
    {
        PackageRemoveItem removeItem = new PackageRemoveItem()

        .............blah blah blah

        await this.deviceRepository.RemovePackageAsync(removeItem);
        return  this.Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(removeItem.Machines));
    }
```

Method:

```
    public async Task RemovePackageAsync(PackageRemoveItem removeItem, CancellationToken cancelToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int[] machines = removeItem.Machines.Keys.ToArray();
            .......


        });
    }
```

However, when I run this in debug my ajax response waits until my "RemovePackageAsync" finishes. What I'm trying to achieve here is to have this method be called on a different thread, let it execute and NOT wait for it to finish but to get "true" response right away from the controller.

ajax call => controller => call method on new thread, do NOT wait for it to finish BUT return true => let method run as long as it needs. and I get to do other stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous controllers work asynchronous just *inside* the webserver to free threads from the threadpool to handle concurrent requests. The browser still waits synchronous for the result to be returned by your action.

What you need is a standard controller action which just spawns a thread or a task and returns immediately.

But that way you can't return any resulting data.

Comment: +1 with a minor adjustment: To be safe from app restarts and server crashes, the controller action should queue the request to persistent storage (Azure Queues / MSMQ) and then have *another service* read that queue and process the actual command.